# Javascript toolbar plugin CSS Inheritance

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've built a little javascript plugin that can be accessed by clicking the relevant button on my browser toolbar.

On some sites it works fine, but on others it looks awful, mainly because it is picking up CSS styles from the parent page.

When building a toolbar plugin is there anything I can do/rules to follow in order to prevent my tool from inheriting styles from the browser page.

Comment: sorry, a plugin for what? for Firefox? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phenomenon at work is **css inheritance**.
Everything you add to a page will be styled according to the css for that page.
You need to use classes to make the css for your added element more specific that the other rules applying to it from the page's own css.

Your css rules for your new element needs to be more **specific** than the other rules applying to it. A bit like in spoken language, being specific means referring to something in more detail.

Rule 1

> table tbody td span{ font-weight: bold; }

Rule 2

> table span{ font-weight: normal; }

In this case, rule 1 will "win" over rule 2, because it is more **specific**.

For a quick explanation, look at htmldog's [page on css specificty](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/)

You want to clear the css of any style coming in, then add them again after.
Say it's all in a div with class="jibber-nav"

You could do this:

```
.jibber-nav,
.jibber-nav ul,
.jibber-nav li,
.jibber-nav a{
  background: none;
  color: #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/**** then add style you want *******/

.jibber-nav li{
  border: 2px solid #123456;
  border: radius: 4px;
}

.jibber-nav a{
  color: #097654;
}
```

If all else fails, you can append [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) to all your css rules, but that would make you a bad person and not to be trusted. Actually it just increases the risk of making your code a big confusing pain to work with, but that's the same thing.

Comment: Makes sense. Will give it a go. Cheers

Comment: This has been great info. Really helped me out. Thanks.